# Issue with Powershell parsing in 4.0

Tags: powershell

I am having issues with the snippet below with Powershell 4.0 on 2012 R2:

```
$query = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="' +
                     $disk.DeviceID.replace('\','\\') +
                     '"} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition'
```

On my Windows 7 laptop running Powershell 2.0 this works fine both in the Powershell cli and in a .ps1 script. In Powershell 4.0 if I run it in the cli it works fine, but if I run it out of a .ps1 script I get:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\temp\perf.ps1:94 char:1
+ $part_query =  'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="' + $disk.DeviceID.rep ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ( [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

After some debug I think the issue is with `.replace('\\','\\\')`.

I have tried `.replace('\\\','\\\\\\\')` but I get the same error.

Full code:

```
$diskdrives = get-wmiobject Win32_DiskDrive | sort Index

    foreach ( $disk in $diskdrives ) {
 write $disk
        $scsi_details = 'SCSI ' + $disk.SCSIBus         + ':' +
                                  $disk.SCSILogicalUnit + ':' +
                                  $disk.SCSIPort        + ':' +
                                  $disk.SCSITargetID


        #$part_query = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="' + $disk.DeviceID.replace('\','\\') + '"} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition'
$part_query =  'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="' + $disk.DeviceID.replace('\\','\\\') + '"} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition'
        $partitions = @( get-wmiobject -query $part_query | 
                         sort StartingOffset )
        foreach ($partition in $partitions) {

            $vol_query = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="' +
                         $partition.DeviceID +
                         '"} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition'
            $volumes   = @(get-wmiobject -query $vol_query)


            foreach ( $volume in $volumes) {
                $allDiskInfo += $($volume.name + ' ' +
                          $volume.FileSystem + ' ' + $disk.Index + ' '
                       ) | Out-String -stream

            } # end foreach vol

        } # end foreach part




} # end foreach disk
```

Comment: The issue is with `$disk` - it's not initialised or, more specifically, the `DeviceID` property is null. Where's the rest of the script?

Comment: either $disk or $disk.deviceid is null

Comment: Here is the full code, if $disk or deviceID were null I wouldn't think it would work in any Powershell version, this does work in 2.0. I put the full code in the original post. The output of the write $disk is: \\ICTM-CLARK\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0"

Comment: FWIW Running your code with PowerShell 3.0 has no errors as long as i use `('\','\\')` for the replace.

Comment: @Matt Same here, PowerShell 4.0 on Win7, no problems. Sounds to me like OP has a DiskDrive with no associated physical DeviceID

Comment: What is the output from `write $disk` look like before the error? Is the `deviceid` populated in that output. 4.0 is not the only difference. Are you running this on a different computer as well?

Comment: Yes, this is run on the same machine. Looks like in 2.0 $disk.gettype() is ManagementObject System.Management.ManagementBaseObject in 4.0 $disk.gettype() is String Sytem.Object. So 4.0 is typing it differently.

Comment: i´m on v4 too and for me its System.Management.ManagementBaseObject

Comment: @Paul Does his code work on your system? The type name changes might just be superficial.

Comment: Works well for me, I get `E: NTFS 0 C: NTFS 1 D: NTFS 2 G: NTFS 3 F: NTFS 4 O: NTFS 5 E: NTFS 0 C: NTFS 1 D: NTFS 2 G: NTFS 3 F: NTFS 4 O: NTFS 5 E: NTFS 0 C: NTFS 1 D: NTFS 2 G: NTFS 3 F: NTFS 4 O: NTFS 5 `

Comment: That is the output I'm looking for. Not sure why I'm getting the null error.

Comment: @JohnKennedy do you have null/empty DeviceID's?

Comment: @matt yes it does work fine and i get the same output as micky

Answer (score 0):

When I declared $disks I made it [string]. What I think happened is that Powershell 2.0 coerced it back to the system object but Powershell 4.0 must have stronger typing rules and was not coercing it from what I declared it as. Once I took [string] out of the declaration, it works on 4.0.
Thanks for the responses!!